# Jest - changing mock implementation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a mock file of my `api.js` located in `__mocks__/api.js` with default implementation like this:

```
export function api() {
  return {
    systemInfo: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ system_info: { mi_workers_count: 3 } }))
  }
}
```

however I want to change this default behaviour in one test, so I've tried to do it following way which doesn't work:

```
import { api as mockApi } from "__mocks__/api" //tried also from original impl. file "api"

test("something", async () => {
  console.log(mockApi().systemInfo.getMockImplementation()())
  mockApi().systemInfo.mockImplementationOnce(() => 
    Promise.resolve({ system_info: { mi_workers_count: 1 } })
  )
  console.log(mockApi().systemInfo.getMockImplementation()())
})
```

both `console.log` will return same, origin promise response implemented in `__mocks__/api`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, a spy should be accessible outside the scope it's defined. Since it's defined inside `api`, this cannot be done, `mockApi().systemInfo !== mockApi().systemInfo`.

The spy can be exported separately:

```
export const mockSystemInfo = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ system_info: { mi_workers_count: 3 } }));

export function api() {
  return {
    systemInfo: mockSystemInfo
  }
}
```

The implementation can be changed with:

```
mockSystemInfo.mockImplementationOnce(...)
```